# Manipulating formatted numbers in a page

Tags: javascript, parsing, formatting, numbers

I'm working with numerical data I.e. adding, subtracting, present valuing, etc, numbers in a page.  However, I format them and print them to the screen.  Say I want to add a column of numbers, I have to parse for commas etc.  Is there a paradigm to use the actual data, an not have to parse the DOM data? Or should I store both data in the page, but save the numbers as an attribute?

Answer (score 0):

*If* I understand your question correctly, it sounds like you might be looking for [Angular](https://angularjs.org/) or some other form of two way data binding.  Using that framework, you would be able to setup a template to reflect automatically to your "data model" (some javascript construct in memory) and have it update automatically to reflect changes in that model.  You can also use "filters" when drawing it to the page to make the raw number display as currency.

Answer (score 0):

create a template. and then pass variables to it, and it spits out html
--mustache (multi types, you want javascript)
--handlerbars.js

=================

MISC javascript code that might be worth while to you.

```
    // would split things up on underscore _   
    // replace underscore with comma if wanted. 
        var something = your_something.split('_');  


    //some for loops
    for( var i in something) {
    var a = something[i];
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < something.length; i++) {
    var a = something[i];
    }

    regex, .match, .replace  
// are javascript string commands for....
// find(something) and replace with (something) doing.  
// other words dealing with decimal points, dollar signs etc.. 
// and extracting numbers or like.

//dealing with objects and arrays and getting data from them.
something['name'] //= something.name = same thing in many situations.
something[i].name 
something[i][x]
something.name.x

var a = '<table>';
a+= '<tr>';
a+= '<td>;
//a = <table><tr><td>

.innerhtml or .append
//used to add stuff to the dom / html stuff already in the something.html file.
```

json.parse() // may come up

there are way more better examples than i can do out there. but hopefully pickup some keywords that would reveal better internet searches for examples.

normally doing for me... google search "javascript .innerhtml" and open 4 to 10 results i get back and normally find enough to satisfy what i want.

jtables.com i want to say, or datatables.net i also want to say deal with sort spreadhsheet like columns and sorting data that the end user can do.

cookies, localstorage, indexeddb.  localstorage most likely easier of the 3 with enough power for simple application and storing information.